# libgdx shader in actor

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have custom group, which consist of some actors, and also uses custom shader in its `draw()`

It looks like:

```
override fun draw(batch: Batch, parentAlpha: Float) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha)
    Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(false)
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND)
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    val sh = stage.batch.shader // Save current shader
    stage.batch.shader = shader // Set custom shader
    shader.begin()
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", stage.camera.combined)
    shader.setUniformf("u_color", color)
    shader.setUniformf("u_scale", scale)
    shader.setUniformf("u_radius", radius)
    shader.setUniformf("u_pos_center", v)
    mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
    shader.end()
    stage.batch.shader = sh // Restore default shader
}
```

All the actors in the group are drawn, but not custom shader.

Not sure I do it correctly. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make those direct OpenGL calls because those are GL parameters that SpriteBatch manages for itself so you could be messing up its defaults for other actors it draws later. You can set blend functions and enable blending on the batch directly. SpriteBatch already disables depth testing and masking by default.

If you want to draw the children of this group with that shader, move `super.draw` to after you've set the shader parameters. Do not call `shader.begin()` or `end()`, as these are handled for you by the batch.

But if you are just drawing that custom mesh, then it doesn't make sense for you to be messing with the batch's shader at all. Instead, you should call `batch.end` at the beginning of this method (maybe after calling `super.draw`), and call `batch.begin` at the end of this method. Without seeing your custom shader or how you set up your mesh, it's not possible to determine if there are additional issues preventing you from seeing your mesh.